# Evenly spaced text fields

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I'm creating a fillable pdf using Rmarkdown, and I would like text fields to line up with one another. Here's the code I'm using:

```
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[name=title1]{Title} \\\\
    \TextField[name=contributors]{Contributor(s)} \\\\
\end{Form}
```

Which looks like:
[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please make a full minimal example. That is a lot easier to work with than a sniplet like this. For example, where does the `Form` env come from or the `\TextField` command? Help us help you.

Comment: Try with `\TextField[name=title1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{Title}\phantom{Contributor(s)}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Title &
    \TextField[name=title1]{} \\\\
    Contributor(s) &
    \TextField[name=contributors]{} 
\end{tabular}
\end{Form} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The other way is with `\phantom`, as Werner mentioned in a comment.  That could be embodied in a macro `\UniformTextField` with the `\theWidest` defining the widest field in the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\UniformTextField[2][1]{%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\theWidest}%
  \TextField[#1]{\makebox[\wd2][l]{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
\def\theWidest{Cont‌​ributor(s)}
\noindent\begin{Form}
    \UniformTextField[name=title1]{Title} \\\\
    \UniformTextField[name=contributors]{Contributor(s)} \\\\
\end{Form}  
\end{document}
```